# Javadoc: Can {@code ...} have a line break?

Tags: java, javadoc

Is it ok for `@code` to be split across two lines? For example, is this valid Javadoc?

```
/**
 * Some very long description. Using {@code
 * @Nullable} is recommended.
 */
void foo() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Of course. You just can't start a line with the **@** character within a @code block. If you want to do something like this then place the tag character directly after the **{@code** like this:  `Some very long description. Using {@code @Nullable} is recommended.`. Is a bug they just don't want to fix.